# Django does not load CSS properly for some template files

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-views

I'm designing my page with twitter-bootstrap.. I have made a **base.html** file which will be my global base file for all the templates to extend.

My problem is when i extend the **base.html** for all the templates. It does not display the CSS rather displays everything in plain HTML. And when i view the page source, the javascript and CSS files are visible. ( which mean those files are loaded properly but not displayed )

In **settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = '/home/User/workspace/project/static'
```

My project structure is as follows:

```
-App1
   -templates
     - sample.html (which extends base.html)
-App2
-App3
-App4
-static
  -css
     -bootstrap.css
  -js
     -bootstrap.js
     -jquery.js
-templates
  -base.html
```

I don't understand what can be the problem. Any help would be really great!

Comment: Can you share your templatedirs? perhaps sample.html can't find base.html because you only added the main templates directory?

Comment: Also, how are you trying to add the staticfiles to your templates?

Comment: What does the title have to do with the actual question?

Comment: @Daniel It was by mistake...i also had another question which was the title i putforth..i have changes it though now.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the STATICFILES_DIRS like a string.

import os and use sep function to find your static files dirs. This is the way thaT I do:

```
import os
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.sep.join([os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'static']),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did and that really helped me was :

1. go to settings.py and add --> STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')] at the end of file.
2. Go to the base html template in your templates folder, and add these 2 lines in the head section  (Just make sure you create a folder in static. in my case it is css as you can see below, could be different name ):

   a) `{% load static %}`
   b) `<link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="{% static 'css/mystyle.css'%}">`

Comment: Sorry guys I had to repost it because the first time I posted it, it did not show the entire post.